# How to fix ffmpeg & mencoder pushing Persian (RTL) subtitles reversed?

Tags: ffmpeg, right-to-left, subtitle, mencoder, farsi

I'm trying to build an application to burn subtitles on videos. The specific task to do is burning Persian (Right-to-left language) subtitles. But I have a problem with it.

When I got several words simuntaneously without any "Enter" between them, the `ffmpeg` or `mencoder` push the lines to up. for example if I have three lines, the third lines comes on first line, then the second line, and then the first line prints on the screen.

I have attached two screenshot to be clear about it. As you may see in the second one, there are 9 lines of persian subtitle which should be aligned from 1 on top to 9 on the bottom, but the 9th line appears on the first line on top.

[image]

[image]

I'm using this code at the moment to burn the subtitles on mp4 videos:

```
mencoder video.mp4 -sub subtitle.srt -utf8  -o output.mp4 -oac pcm -ovc lavc
```

Comment: This is up for close as off-topic. Maybe you should frame it as a shell or scripting problem to try and keep it on-topic. Otherwise, it might be more appropriate for Super User.